# How to set zapcc as default in Manjaro?

Tags: c++, c, manjaro

Hey been thinking about setting zapcc as default C/C++ compiler but can not find anything on how to set it up on Manjaro Linux with latest updates.

is `CC=zapcc` right thing to do?

Regards.

Tried 'CC=zapcc`

None to show

None

Comment: It's the right thing to do, but... where did you set it?

Comment: used it directly in terminal.

Comment: It will not work after the next command, unless you do `export CC=zapcc`. You might also want to put that in your `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or whatever shell you use

Comment: Thanks for answer :) will try when im back home. Ps. These will set zapcc for both C and C++?

Comment: Should be `CXX` for the C++ compiler

Comment: In .bashrc only CC=zapcc and CXX=zapcc++ or expot needs to be here too?